Cordova Android build fails with "Unsupported class file major version 66"
I created a simple Cordova project. I installed Cordova using npm install -g cordova and created my app using cordova create test-project. I changed no configs or anything, just added an h1 in the index.html file.
I want to build the app for android. So I ran cordova platform add android and tried to build it using cordova build android, but this build fails with the following gradle error:
* What went wrong:
BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 66
> Unsupported class file major version 66

When I run cordova requirements, it looks like this:
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 22.0.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
Command failed with ENOENT: avdmanager list target
spawn avdmanager ENOENT
Gradle: installed /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gradle/8.10.1/bin/gradle

So Android target seems to be missing, but I have no idea how to install it, and on the Platform Guide page for Android in the Cordova docs it's not mentioned. I installed Android SDK version 13 in Android Studio (because in package.json, it says "cordova-android": "^13.0.0"). However that also didn't work.
Any idea why Gradle is failing here? Do I need to install another version of some crap?
Please tell me if you need any other information to help.
Thank you!

I was able to solve the problem by downloading the required JDK for class version 66, which is Java 17, from the Oracle Downloads page.
I downloaded JDK 17 as a compressed archive into a custom folder I chose and extracted it. Then I set the environment variable JAVA_HOME to the absolute path of the Home directory inside the extracted archive. When I then ran cordova build android again, it worked and created the APK inside platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
Then I sent this APK file to my phone and was (after a security scan) able to install it.

Unsupported class file major version 66 equals JDK 22. Use any compatible Java version, alike maybe JDK 17 (which equals version 61). While the documentation clearly confirms my guess:

The Java Development Kit (JDK) requirement has been increased to version 17 due to the new versions of dependencies and tooling previously described.


Ok so how should I best do this? Should I downgrade the Java installed on my system to JDK 17 or can I modify which version the grade script uses?

Change or pass a different JAVA_HOME or org.gradle.java.home: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_environment_variables

That worked! Thank you
